# TF-Serving saved_model protobuf much slower at inference time

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-serving, inference

So I had trained an object detection model (YOLO-v3) in Tensorflow and saved it using "TF.saved_model" to a serving format to host it using Tensorflow serving. without TF-serving, the regular average inference time per image is 35 ms.

However when I try to serve it on the same machine (localhost) using Tensorflow-serving the inference time per image increases to 1 second (~ 30 times slower!) and I cant figure out why and what is going wrong.

Here's the code I use to convert my graph to a "saved_model.pb" for TF-serving:

```
import tensorflow as tf
IMAGE_H,IMAGE_W = 832,832

def read_pb_return_tensors(graph, pb_file, return_elements):

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(pb_file, 'rb') as f:
        frozen_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        frozen_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with graph.as_default():
        return_elements = tf.import_graph_def(frozen_graph_def,
                                              return_elements=return_elements)
        input_tensor, output_tensors = return_elements[0], return_elements[1:]

    return input_tensor, output_tensors

gpu_nms_graph = tf.Graph()

input_tensor, output_tensors = utils.read_pb_return_tensors(gpu_nms_graph, "./checkpoint/yolov3-logos-{}/yolov3-logos-{}_gpu_nms.pb".format(IMAGE_H,IMAGE_H),
                                           ["Placeholder:0", "concat_10:0", "concat_11:0", "concat_12:0"])

with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=gpu_nms_graph) as sess:
    if os.path.isdir(export_path):
        os.rmdir(export_path)


    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
    #builder = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

    tensor_info_inputs = {
        'inputs': tf.compat.v1.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_tensor)
    }


    tensor_info_outputs = {}
    for k,v in enumerate(output_tensors):
        tensor_info_outputs['output_{}'.format(k)] = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(v)

    detection_signature = (
        tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs=tensor_info_inputs,
            outputs=tensor_info_outputs,
            method_name=tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess, [tf.compat.v1.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                'Detect_logos':
                detection_signature,
                tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
                detection_signature 
                },
        main_op=tf.tables_initializer(),
        strip_default_attrs=True)
    builder.save()
```

I am using Tensorflow 1.14.0 , tensorflow-model-server 1.14.0 and tensorflow-serving-api 1.14.0

I should also mention that few months back i was using the same code to serve a very similar model(also single class YOLO) and even though there was also increased inference time latency (40 ms to 200 ms) but it was less significant. I was using a older version of tensorflow at the time.